# Assistance with Chinese address needed

Tags: translation, terms-of-address

I need to return a product but can't sort how to address it. Any assistance would extremely appreciated.

The (translated) address provided is:

qing xi zhen ju fu lu 38 hao S2-2 dong guan
guang dong 523648
C2

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

do you want a Chinese version address? it should be: 广东省东莞市清溪镇聚富路38号S2-2. and the postcode: 523648.

By the way, it is a good idea to delete your question after getting my answer because of the information security.

Comment: I need the proper English format to create a shipment and return goods sent to me in the US.

Answer (score 0):

For just an English format of a Chinese address to return goods, this could maybe be OK to use. If you want a more formal and secure format, The following would work:

`S2-2, No.38, Jufu Rd., Qingxi, Dongguan, Guangdong, China` with postcode `523648`

Which is just using Western way (from smaller place to bigger place) of naming adresses with properly English-written Chinese Pinyin.

When shipping from other countries to China, The specific address is only read by Chinese staffs, they are all trained to read Pinyin from elementry school. Unnecessary translation only cause extra problem for them and maybe you.

However, (assuming that you are using EMS) even the adress is misspelled, staffs from China Post would find a way to send it to the right hand. That's what China Post are famous for in China.

Comment: Also I just assume the S2-2 is the room number or something same as that. For a more accurate answer you should paste the Chinese address in Chinese.